# How to sort a name (String) list in Swift?

Tags: swift2

There is a name list without any order. 
How to sort name list by alphabet order?
What I mean is how to compare two strings to find out greater one?
Is there any existing method or function to do this like Java does?

In Java, we can use

```
"abc".compareTo("abb");
```

to compare strings greater or smaller.

Comment: @marek-r I've canceled your edit because it introduced irrelevant tags. This question is not related to NSString or OSX (this Swift code can be multiplatform). Please avoid adding tags that are not needed. Thank you.

Comment: @kb920 My comment to Marek-R also applies to you. This question is not related to iOS. Please don't add irrelevant tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can use sort function of array like below,

```
let names = ["Chris", "Alex", "Ewa", "Barry", "Daniella"]

var reversed = names.sort({s1,s2 in s1 < s2})

//var reversed = names.sort {$0 < $1} // Shorter version of Closure.

print(reversed)
```

Comment: Note also that `<` as used above will use lexicographical comparison which will sort e.g. `"Daniella"` prior to `"alexanda"`, which possibly is not what the OP intends. To sort without case-sensitivity, modify the above to e.g. `let sorted = names.sort{$0.lowercaseString < $1.lowercaseString}`.

Comment: @anish-parajuli It's a Swift Array, not an NSArray... Please don't do unnecessary edits. Thanks.